# C# extract - XML Child Node Attributes

Tags: c#, html, arrays, xml, xml-parsing

Sample of XML File

```
<NvM_DataManager_Blocks
        AlignmentConstraint="ManagedBy_DataManager"
        GenerateBlockAccessAPI="Yes" UseProtectedSections="Yes" UseRteForDataManagerInterface="No">
        <DATA_MANAGER_EEPROM_BLOCK Block_Crc_Type="NVM_CRC16"
            Block_Priority="255" Block_Type="NVM_BLOCK_NATIVE"
            ErrorCallback="" FeeOrEa_BlockId=""
            Name="DataManager_Block_01"
            Project_specific_information=""
            Resistant_To_Changed_SW="No" Storage_In="Fee" Write_Only_At_WriteAll="No">
            <DATA_ELEMENT CreateCommitedApi="Yes" DataSize=""
                DataSize_bit="" Data_type="uint8" Default_Value="66"
                Header_file="" Name="DataManager_DataElement_01"
                Number_Of_Planned_Writes="255" VariantInit="No"/>
            <DATA_ELEMENT CreateCommitedApi="Yes" DataSize=""
                DataSize_bit="" Data_type="uint32"
                Default_Value="255" Header_file=""
                Name="DataManager_DataElement_02"
                Number_Of_Planned_Writes="363" VariantInit="No"/>
        </DATA_MANAGER_EEPROM_BLOCK>
```

---

This is my code.

```
//Load xml

XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\Program\\file.xml");
var blocks2 = (from r in xdoc.Descendants("DATA_MANAGER_EEPROM_BLOCK")
              select new
              {
                  Name = r.Attribute("Name").Value,

//This line below does not the produce what is req. I need some help on how to fix this.

                  Sub_Elements = xdoc.Descendants("DATA_MANAGER_EEPROM_BLOCK").Descendants("DATA_ELEMENT")

              }).ToList();
```

However, I have some issue to extract the sub elements : DataManager_DataElement_01 & DataManager_DataElement_02 and their attributes.

Comment: Post sample of xml file.

Comment: Check XDocument if you want to parse xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("CrC_Type", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Priority", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Block_Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Data_Type", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Default_Value", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Element_Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Planned_Writes", typeof(int));

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            foreach (XElement block in doc.Descendants("DATA_MANAGER_EEPROM_BLOCK"))
            {
                string crcType = (string)block.Attribute("Block_Crc_Type");
                int blockPriority = (int)block.Attribute("Block_Priority");
                string blockType = (string)block.Attribute("Block_Type");
                string blockName = (string)block.Attribute("Name");

                foreach(XElement element in block.Elements("DATA_ELEMENT"))
                {
                    string dataType = (string)element.Attribute("Data_type");
                    int defaultValue = (int)element.Attribute("Default_Value");
                    string elementName = (string)element.Attribute("Name");
                    int plannedWrites = (int)element.Attribute("Number_Of_Planned_Writes");

                    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                        crcType,
                        blockPriority,
                        blockType,
                        blockName,
                        dataType,
                        defaultValue,
                        elementName,
                        plannedWrites
                    });    
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  will try it :)